# Using hook_theme_registry_alter to only modify specific pages instead of all pages

Tags: 6, hooks, theming

I have a custom module which invokes the hook_theme_registry_alter() to modify the presentation of some input fields.

However, I've discovered that the overridden styling is affecting ALL input fields on my entire site.

This is not good!

How to I make it so that my implementation of the hook_theme_registry_alter() is only seen on my module's pages?

Here is my function, and it is applying the theming functions to ALL radio and form elements on our site.

```
function MY_MODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  if (isset($theme_registry['radio'])) {
    $theme_registry['radios']['function'] = "MY_MODULE_radios";
    $theme_registry['radio']['function'] = "MY_MODULE_radio";
    $theme_registry['form_element']['function'] = "MY_MODULE_element";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For simple alterations, instead of implementing `hook_elements()`, you could simply implement [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) or it's cousin [`hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/6). Both of these functions will effectively allow you to (as their name suggests) alter a form's input elements, and they are much easier to implement than `hook_elements()`. The former gets called for every function in the website, while the later only gets called for the `FORM_ID` that you specified in your hook implementation.

If the ID of the form you wish to modify is `my_form`, then `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` would be written as `hook_form_my_form_alter()`. If you want a more thorough explanation of these two hooks, I highly recommend reading [Lullabot's writeup on modifying Drupal 6 Forms](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implementing `hook_theme_registry_alter()` that changes the theme implementations for every module, you could define new form fields using [hook_elements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_elements/6). In this way you can implement a new radio field that is used only from your module, and that render a radio field in a customized way.
The default field definitions implemented by Drupal are contained in [system_elements()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.module/function/system_elements/6), which defines the form fields you are interested to using the following arrays:

```
  $type['radios'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#process' => array('expand_radios'),
  );
  $type['radio'] = array(
    '#input' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => NULL,
    '#process' => array('form_expand_ahah'),
  );
```

Using your form fields, you would just replace code similar to the first snippet with code similar to the second snippet.

```
$form['posting_settings']['comment_preview'] = array(
  '#type' => 'radios', 
  '#title' => t('Preview comment'), 
  '#default_value' => variable_get('comment_preview', 1), 
  '#options' => array(t('Optional'), t('Required')),
);
```

```
$form['posting_settings']['comment_preview'] = array(
  '#type' => 'mymodule_radios', 
  '#title' => t('Preview comment'), 
  '#default_value' => variable_get('comment_preview', 1), 
  '#options' => array(t('Optional'), t('Required')),
);
```

As only your module would use the "mymodule_radios" form field type, only your module would render the "radios" form field in a different way.

In Drupal 7, the hook has been renamed to [hook_element_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7).

For more information, see [Creating Custom Elements Using Drupal 6.x](http://drupal.org/node/169815).

Comment: The only way I can get this to work is if in the custom mymodule_radios function I pass the $element array through the theme(form_element) function. Which means I have to customize that as well. That works, but I don't have any of my radio buttons. How do I tell it to build the radios and ALSO to theme the RADIO elements inside with a custom function?

Comment: "Creating Custom Elements Using Drupal 6.x" reports the following sentence: "If you use hook_elements() to define an element type, there is an implicit assumption that there will be a theme function with the same name as the element type used to render HTML of its instances."

Comment: I have created the theme functions too. My issue comes that it's rendering the radios element just fine, but not the CHILDREN inside it. So I get a radio element formatted the way I want with no actual button choices.

Comment: [theme_radios()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_radios/6) uses the following code: `theme('form_element', $element, $element['#children']);`. Even if you use a different theme function, you should still theme the child elements.

Comment: When I use that, I don't GET any children, though. I get the theme'd radios element with no children. I have a seperate theme_mymodule_radio function but that doesn't seem to get called at all.

Comment: Did you define that theme function in `hook_theme()`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1393/discussion-between-oranges13-and-kiamlaluno)